# PHP/MySQL Combining two queries to reduce loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query, whos results then loop out to run another query and retrieve another set of results, but I would like to combine these so I am not running so many queries and to speed everything up, but I've tried a few iterations and either get *null* results, or errors with the syntax.
So looking for some community magic here.

Query 1:

```
SELECT tou_tracking_start, tou_tracking_end, tou_tracking_timestart,
tou_tracking_timeend, tou_tracking_units, daytype_ID 
FROM db_tou_tracking 
WHERE ICP_ID = '39' 
AND (tou_tracking_start >= '2013-01-01' AND tou_tracking_end <= '2013-12-31')
```

Which loops out its results and are then used in the next query:

```
SELECT rates_tou_rate, rates_tou_PPD FROM db_rates_tou 
WHERE (rates_tou_start <= '" .$tou_tracking_start . 
    "' AND rates_tou_end >= '" . $tou_tracking_end . "') 
AND (rates_tou_timestart <= '" . $tou_tracking_timestart . 
    "' AND rates_tou_timeend >= '" . $tou_tracking_timeend . "') 
AND daytype_ID = ".$tou_tracking_daytype_ID." 
LIMIT 1
```

If these can be combined, then I only need to select:

- *tou_tracking_start*
- *tou_tracking_end*
- *rates_tou_rate*
- *rates_tou_PPD*

Many thanks in advance for the help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a JOIN

```
SELECT tt.tou_tracking_start, tt.tou_tracking_end, rt.rates_tou_rate, rt.rates_tou_PPD
FROM db_tou_tracking tt
JOIN db_rates_tou rt ON rt.daytypeID = tt.daytype_ID
AND (tt.tou_tracking_start >= '2013-01-01' AND tt.tou_tracking_end <= '2013-12-31')
```

tt is an alias for db_tou_tracking and rt is an alias for db_rates_tou.

I assume they are matched by daytype_ID in both tables and there is a 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: Not quite, its not grabbing the correct *rt.rates_tou_rate*. It is getting the 1st rate and applying that to every date and time, and then the next rate and applying it again to the next date and all the times. So ending up with 70000+ results which isn't correct.

Comment: Are there more than 1 db_rates_tou for every db_tou_tracking? If not then double check the field names on join are correct

Comment: no. But it depends on tt.tou_tracking_timestart and tt.tou_tracking_timeend